# How to align list items so it does not overlap

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<ul>

<li>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
</li>

<li>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>line 2 line 2 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
</li>

</ul>
```

How it looks:

[image]

When list description overlaps, how can I align them straight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to add `display:flex` to `li`:

```css
ul {
  max-width: 200px;
}
li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
<li>
    <span class="fa fa-check"></span> line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
  </li>

  <li>
    <span class="fa fa-check"></span> line 2 line 2 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to put the icon in the `::before` pseudo element, and then position the icon to the left of each list item.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}

li:before {
  content: "\e013";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
  </li>
  <li>
    line 2 line 2 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1
  </li>
</ul>
```